# Will this equation ever have an positive integer value?

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, diophantine-equations, fractions, integers

Imagine we have some set of positive integers $\{k_1,k_2,...k_n\}$. We are given this formula

$$
x = \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}3^{n-i}2^{\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}k_j}}{2^{\sum_{i=1}^nk_i}-3^n}
$$

and need to find if there will every be an integer solution for any set given besides the trivial solution $\{2\}$

Example:

Say the set was $\{2, 3, 1\}$, then our equation would be

$$
x = \dfrac{3^2+3*2^2+2^{2+3}}{2^{2+3+1}-3^3} = \dfrac{53}{37}
$$

Even saying how to go about solving a problem like this with a hint would be incredibly helpful. Thank you!